# Reading the syntax off of this listing at scala-lang

Tags: scala

Just learning some basic stuff here.

It appears the count method for Vector will be useful to me for an exercise I'm working on, but from reading its entry at scala-lang I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how to use it, syntactically speaking.

Here's what the entry says:

```
count(p: (A) => Boolean): Int
```

I think that's supposed to be telling me the syntax to use when calling the method.

It tells me that "p" is the predicate to be satisfied. Okay, I know what a predicate is in the abstact. What does a predicate look like in Scala though?

Then there's a colon. Do I type that? Or is this meta-linguistic notation of some kind?

Then there's a rocket. Okay. Then that word Boolean--but what is it doing there? I assume I don't literally type **"Boolean."** (Do I?)

Anyway, hopefully you see my problem(s).

How does this work?

Comment: I am really sorry. I swear I didn't type the question lightly. I pondered this for a really long time before resorting to wasting people's time here with the question. But as it happens, within a minute of typing it, I had an epiphany, and I figured it out.

The "p:" is saying "predicate of the following form," the "(A)" is saying "put arguments in parentheses here", the "rocket boolean" is saying "put a rocket followed by a boolean expression here."

Got it.

Sorry and thanks!

Comment: then answer the question and accept it ;-)

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't be a bad idea to start with a tutorial on Scala, or just programming in general.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I am working through a tutorial on Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

`count` needs a parameter `p` of type (`:`) `A` to (rocket) `Boolean`, where 'A' is the type of elements stored by the vector. So you have to provide a function from `A` to `Boolean`.

So you can use it like this:

```
val v = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  // == Vector[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
def odd(elem: Int): Boolean = {
  elem % 2 == 0
}
v.count(odd) // == 3
```

Or using some syntactic sugar:

```
val v = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  // == Vector[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
v.count(_ % 2 == 0) // == 3
```